# Error: Failed to lookup view "subscribers/index" in views directory mocha/chai test code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

Here is the error i'm getting:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "subscribers/index" in views directory
```

This is my directory tree:

```
+---controllers
|       coursesController.js
|       errorController.js
|       homeController.js
|       subscribersController.js
|       usersController.js       
+---models
|       course.js
|       subscriber.js
|       user.js
+---routes
|       apiRoutes.js
|       courseRoutes.js
|       errorRoutes.js
|       homeRoutes.js
|       index.js
|       subscriberRoutes.js
|       userRoutes.js      
+---test
|       usersControllerSpec.js
|       userSpec.js    
\---views
    |   .DS_Store
    |   contact.ejs
    |   courses.ejs
    |   error.ejs
    |   index.ejs
    |   layout.ejs
    |   thanks.ejs  
    +---courses
    |       edit.ejs
    |       index.ejs
    |       new.ejs
    |       show.ejs
    |       _coursesModal.ejs
    |       
    +---partials
    |       navigation.ejs     
    +---subscribers
    |       .DS_Store
    |       edit.ejs
    |       index.ejs
    |       new.ejs
    |       show.ejs    
    \---users
            edit.ejs
            index.ejs
            login.ejs
            new.ejs
            show.ejs    
main.js    
...
```

In **main.js** this is what my app configuration looks like for view, there is more code in here but I dont want this post to be all code:

```
...
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
...
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render("index");
});
app.use(
  methodOverride("_method", {
    methods: ["POST", "GET"]
  })
...
});
```

This is what the test code looks like in **test -> usersControllerSpec.js** to try to get all the subscribers:

```
  describe("/subscribers GET", () => {
    it("it should GET all the subscribers", done => {
      chai
        .request(app)
        .get("/subscribers")
        .end((errors, res) => {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          expect(errors).to.be.equal(null);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
```

I am new to ejs/nodejs/express so I was wondering why the test had an error getting the subscribers/index.

Answer (score 0):

copying the `views` folder in the `test` folder fixed my issue